# How to get mac address of devices who open my website using php

Tags: php

Basically my aim is to restrict people visiting my website.
I tried this - working fine locally but not working when I make the website live.

```
    function mac(){
       ob_start();
    
         system('ipconfig/all');
         $mycom = ob_get_contents();
        ob_clean();
        $findme = "Physical";
         $pmac = strpos($mycom, $findme);
         $mac = substr($mycom, ($pmac + 36), 17);
         return $mac; 
     }
```

Please suggest how to get MAC address of visiting user's device using php.

Comment: MAC addresses are only broadcast on a LAN. Once you put the Internet between the server and the client you can't get hold of it.

Comment: @Quentin can you please suggest a better way to  restrict user access to website

Comment: Username + Password + 2FA